# Fast load data into file split to tables connect by id

Tags: mysql, file, load

Have a MySQL database using InnoDB and Foreign Keys...

I need to import 100MiB of data from a huge CSV file and split it into two tables and the records have to be like follows

```
Table1
id|data|data2

Table2
id|table1_id|data3
```

Where `Table2.table1_id` is a foreign key referencing `Table1.id`.

The MySQL sequence for one instance would look like this

1. Load file into a temporary table
2. After that do an insert from temporary table to the needed
3. Get the last insert ID
4. Do the last insert group using this reference id...

That is utterly slow...

How do I do this using file load into...? Any real ideas with high speed result?

Comment: 2. step - 4. step is of course in a loop :)

And for reference - 8000 rec/sec is SLOW... need at least 20 000 rec/sec

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily add column `data3` to `Table1` (I also add a `done` column to distinguish records which originate from the CSV from those that already exist/originate from elsewhere):

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
  ADD COLUMN data3 TEXT,
  ADD COLUMN done BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE;

LOAD DATA
  INFILE '/path/to/csv'
  INTO TABLE Table1 (data, data2, data3)
  SET done = FALSE;

INSERT
  INTO Table2 (table1_id, data3)
  SELECT (id, data3) FROM Table1 WHERE NOT done;

ALTER TABLE Table1
  DROP COLUMN data3,
  DROP COLUMN done;
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is far from a solution... Logically the structure of the table can not be regularly changed... This is a procedure that will be called all the time because a load of such files will be uploaded on a daily basis... The structures of the tables are set and the solution has to deal with that... This is just a simple example of the structure the real structure would take a A4 page to just copy the create code... So are there any real ideas how to use load data in file function when I have 2 different tables that have to be linked via foreign key? I thought I made that clear...sorry

Comment: @user663184: I presume that the structure of the table cannot be (temporarily) changed because there may be concurrent `SELECT * FROM Table1` or `INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ...` queries that might cause issues within the client applications should there unexpectedly be two additional columns?  To avoid those problems, you could go via a temporary table (but if there might be concurrent `INSERT` statements from elsewhere, you'd need to lock `Table1` during the `LOAD` and `INSERT ... SELECT` - in which case you may as well just lock `Table1` whilst doing the above as originally suggested...)

Comment: PS: if this is an operation you are likely to perform regularly, you could just make the additional columns permanent and `UPDATE Table1 SET done = TRUE WHERE done = FALSE` instead of the second `ALTER TABLE` command (although you'd need to do it in a transaction to preserve atomicity).